# No such table .. when I modify the table in android eclipse

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I have a database and I import it to my project (android mobile application ) it works and it retrieve the data from the tables, but when I modify the database by adding tables or rows through the sqlite database browser, then I clean the project and import the new database and uninstall the project from my device and run it again it force stop the application and in the log section it tells that there is no such table ..

Even when I create new database and import it to the project, it is not working.

```
10-11 13:55:03.152: E/SQLiteLog(10632): (1) no such table: facilities
10-11 13:55:03.162: D/AndroidRuntime(10632): Shutting down VM
10-11 13:55:03.162: W/dalvikvm(10632): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419b6700)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.buttontest/com.example.buttontest.WhereToGo}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: facilities (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT category as '_id' FROM facilities
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2054)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:154)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:546)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: facilities (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT category as '_id' FROM facilities
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at com.example.buttontest.WhereToGo.listNotes(WhereToGo.java:34)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at com.example.buttontest.WhereToGo.onStart(WhereToGo.java:28)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5143)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
10-11 13:55:03.182: E/AndroidRuntime(10632):    ... 18 more
10-11 13:55:04.832: I/Process(10632): Sending signal. PID: 10632 SIG: 9
```

Here is my code:

DataBaseHelper.java

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{ 
private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window 
//destination path (location) of our database on device 
private static String DB_PATH = "";  
private static String DB_NAME ="btm_";// Database name 
private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;  
private final Context mContext;

public DataBaseHelper(Context context)  
{ 
super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? its Database Version 
DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/"; 
this.mContext = context; 
}    

public void createDataBase() throws IOException 
{ 
//If database not exists copy it from the assets 

boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase(); 
if(!mDataBaseExist) 
{ 
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    if (db.isOpen()){
        db.close();
    }
    this.close(); 
    try  
    { 
        //Copy the database from assests 
        copyDataBase(); 
        Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created"); 
    }  
    catch (IOException mIOException)  
    { 
        throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase"); 
    } 
    } 
    } 
    //Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da Name 
    private boolean checkDataBase() 
    { 
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME); 
    //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists()); 
    return dbFile.exists(); 
    } 

    //Copy the database from assets 
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException 
    { 
    InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME); 
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName); 
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024]; 
    int mLength; 
    while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0) 
    { 
        mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength); 
    } 
    mOutput.flush(); 
    mOutput.close(); 
    mInput.close(); 
    } 

    //Open the database, so we can query it 
    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException 
    { 
    String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
    //Log.v("mPath", mPath); 
    mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY); 
    return mDataBase != null; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public synchronized void close()  
    { 
    if(mDataBase != null) 
        mDataBase.close(); 
        super.close(); 
    }
    public Cursor getData() {  
      String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;  
      mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,  
        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);  
      Cursor c = mDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM category", null);  

      return c;  
     }  
    public Cursor getFacilityData() {  
      String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;  
      mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,  
        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);  
      Cursor c = mDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT _id,name FROM facilities", null);  

      return c;  
     }  
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

And Here is new class with calling the database code:
private void listNotes(){
     SQLiteDatabase db = db_con.getWritableDatabase();
     try {
         Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT category as '_id' " +
                 "FROM facilities ",null );
         final ListAdapter noteAdapter = new
SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c,new String[] {"_id"},new int[]
{android.R.id.text1});
         this.setListAdapter(noteAdapter);
     } finally {
     db.close();
     }
    }
```

Comment: before you uninstall the app, try cleaning all the data first, and then uninstall the app. also if you are adding new tables, you will have to include code for the same in the code file to deal with those tables

Answer (score 1):

**DataBaseHelper.java**

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 
    private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window 
    //destination path (location) of our database on device 
    private static String DB_PATH = "";  
    private static String DB_NAME ="btm_";// Database name 
    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;  
    private final Context mContext;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) { 
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? its Database Version 
        DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/"; 
        this.mContext = context; 
    }    

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException { 
        //If database not exists copy it from the assets 

        boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase(); 
        if(!mDataBaseExist) { 
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            if (db.isOpen()) {
                db.close();
            }
            this.close(); 
            try { 
                //Copy the database from assests 
                copyDataBase(); 
                Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created"); 
            } catch (IOException mIOException) { 
                throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase"); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    //Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da Name 
    private boolean checkDataBase() { 
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME); 
        //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists()); 
        return dbFile.exists(); 
    } 

    //Copy the database from assets 
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException { 
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME); 
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName); 
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024]; 
        int mLength; 
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0) { 
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength); 
        } 
        mOutput.flush(); 
        mOutput.close(); 
        mInput.close(); 
    } 

    //Open the database, so we can query it 
    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException { 
        String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
        //Log.v("mPath", mPath); 
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY); 
        return mDataBase != null; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public synchronized void close() { 
        if(mDataBase != null) 
            mDataBase.close(); 
        super.close(); 
    }

    public Cursor getData() {  
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;  
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,  
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);  
        Cursor c = mDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM category", null);  

        return c;  
    }  

    public Cursor getFacilityData() {  
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;  
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,  
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);  
        Cursor c = mDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT _id,name FROM facilities", null);  

        return c;  
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

And Here is new class with calling the database code:

```
private void listNotes() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = db_con.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT category as '_id' " +
                 "FROM facilities ",null );
        final ListAdapter noteAdapter = new
SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c,new String[] {"_id"},new int[]
{android.R.id.text1});
        this.setListAdapter(noteAdapter);
    } finally {
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited this code into the question. This answer should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a database, the db.onCreate() gets called. So now if it find a database with the matching name, it will not invoke the methods needed to update the tables. So what i normally do is to either, physically delete the database or rename the database on the helper. That way when you try open your database, the db.onCreate() method, won't find a database and will create one.

Comment: Oh and changing the version numbers might also help.